# WPF ComboBox.Selected attached event. exist or not?

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, autocomplete, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio (2015) XAML editor provide in the auto-complete ComboBox member list, an event Named `Selected`.
What is the explanation for this auto-complete mistaken?
[image: auto complete]

`Selected` its NOT WPF ComboBox event ([event list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox_events(v=vs.110).aspx)) but its an event of `ComboBoxItem` (inherited from [ListBoxItem.Selected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem(v=vs.110).aspx)).

why is it?

## EDIT

as @glenThomas'answer (thank), the Selected its attached event inhrited from `Selector`, for easy listen for all child selected event.

But, **its not work...** if i put an handler in `Selected` and i build the project i receive an error:

> 'ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'ComboBox' could be found

Answer (score 8):

`System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox` inherits from `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector`, which has a `Selected` attached event.

An attached event allows you to attach a handler for a particular event to some child element rather than to the parent that actually defines the event, even though neither the object potentially raising the event nor the destination handling instance define or otherwise "own" that event in their namespace.

`System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector` has a `SelectedEvent` field, which backs the `Selected` attached event.

The reason for the `Selected` event is so that you can add one event handler to a control that will be executed when any of the many child controls raise the event. It is much more convenient than attaching event handlers to each of the `ComboBoxItem`'s.

As for why it is included in the XAML code editor's intellisense; I believe that is a bug.
The `Selector` class does have a public field for the selected event:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent SelectedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent( 
            "Selected", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(Selector));
```

But you can't add a handler for the event because the `Selector` class doesn't define the event like this:

```
public event RoutedEventHandler Selected
{ 
    add 
    {
        AddHandler(SelectedEvent, value); 
    }
    remove
    {
        RemoveHandler(SelectedEvent, value); 
    }
}
```

So it doesn't make sense for it to be included in the intellisense for `ComboBox`.

But, `ListBoxItem`, which is the base class for `ComboBoxItem` does define the event for you to attach handlers, so you can attach handlers to the ComboBoxItems

Comment: thank. but as you say, this event has significance only in ListBoxItem and his inheritors. If so, for what it defined as **attached** event, this is normal behavior of the standard event.

Comment: I don't understand you

Answer (score 3):

`Selected` is attached event defined in `Selector` class and is supposed **to be used with Selectors items**. Usually you would write:

```
<ListBoxItem Selector.Selected="OnSelected" />
```

As shown below, ComboBox can be also an item, that's why there is the `Selected` event listed in intellisense:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Selector">
    <ComboBox x:Name="Item1" />
    <ComboBox x:Name="Item2" />
</ListBox>
```

However, combobox must be an item of another selector in order to use the Selected event:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Selector1" Selector.Selected="ThisDoesNotWork"/>
<ListBox x:Name="Selector2">
    <ComboBox x:Name="Item1" Selector.Selected="ThisShouldWorkButDoesnt"/>
     <!-- See edit -->
    <ComboBox x:Name="Item2" />
</ListBox>
```

and the reason, why you dont have to write Selector.Selected=".." but just Selected="..."? Because Combobox is also selector. Similarily, you dont have to write Grid.Column but just Column, when attaching to Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Grid.Column="1" -->
    <Grid Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

At least, this this explain behavior of autocomplete in visual studio.

**EDIT:** neither Selector.Selected nor Selected=".." syntax in controls inherited from Selector does not compile, probably due to bug in XAML parser. But there is workaround using named xml namespace:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Selector2"
         xmlns:p="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=PresentationFramework">
    <ComboBox x:Name="Item1" p:Selector.Selected="Item1_Selected"/>
```

Comment: Did you try what you write? That for me there is an error when a Combo is also a list item.

Comment: Well I have tried it with other controls than ListBoxItem, but not with ComboBox. It seems like a bug in parser. See my edit

Comment: @Lireo Your edit is correct. But the event has no effect, and it will never triger, except when it is in ListBoxItem. Well, why this _attached_ event?

Comment: _why this attached event_ what?

Comment: I have looked at sourcecodes for listbox. If you add FrameworkElement other than ListBoxItem to ListBox.Items, it will be wrapped by ListBoxItem. This is why it does not work with ComboBox inside ListBox. But the wrapping into ListBoxItem does not have to be true for other Selectors. That's probably why you can attach the event to any element.

Comment: `The concept of an attached event enables you to add a handler for a  particular event to an arbitrary element rather than to an element that actually defines or inherits the event` ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb613550(v=vs.100).aspx)). plase give me **one** case for this concept in `Selector.Selected` case.

Comment: triggering an animation inside list item, when the item is selected. It's the selector who defines the event and fires it, but it is fired on the item. And why it is then not defined on the item? because item can be eventually any element. ListBox uses ListBoxItem, ListView uses ListViewItem, DataGrid uses DataGridRow, you own Selector could use anything. Its the same concept as attached properties like Grid.Row or Canvas.Left - you don't know what elements will needs the properties